# How does electric signal go from point A to point B in this schematic?

Tags: signal, schematic, signal-routing

I am trying to figure out what path electricity takes from point A to point B.

I assume it will pass trough some transistors, but how exactly, and why?

For example, I assume it somehow gets to TCA671 - IC1/T3, but does it go from leg 8 to 6, and how?

Highlighting the path would help a lot.

[image: point A to point B, how]

Answer (score 3):

Point **A** is a 12 V supply voltage. It goes through two resistors, R61 and R62, which along with C17 and C18 provide some noise filtering and isolation between stages. From there it goes to the collector of IC1/T1 which is an emitter follower buffering Tr1a, the signal from the emitter of IC1/T1 then goes through an attenuator (R23 - R29) and some switches to the base of IC1/T3, which is your point **B**.